# How to force dark appearance in CarPlay Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, carplay

ist it possible to trigger the dark appearance in the CarPlay simulator (iOS 13)? iPhone and CarPlay are set to dark mode but it is light nevertheless.

Comment: do you mean making it dark mode without setting the dark mode in Settings?

Comment: have you tried to add `User Interface Style` `Dark` on info.plist?

Comment: the dark mode setting has no impact on the appearance. I think the dark mode is automatically triggered by the car.

Comment: @AndresGomez that p.list entry hasn't changed it.

Comment: I know for iOS simulators you can go to Settings/Developer Settings and turn on the dark mode there. Maybe there's a similar settings in the CarPlay simulator?

Comment: I don't see something like that.

Comment: The settings in CarPlay (grid view -> settings -> appearance -> always dark) did nothing? The options are Automatic and Always Dark. If that didn't work, maybe open a radar with Apple